# how to play sound on a href click and mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, mouseover

This is my header:

I want to add sound affect twice:

1. on mouseover on a href from (innerlinks)
2. on click on href from (innerlinks)
   I want a different sound onclick and onmouseover.
   what is the best way?

thanks!

```
<div id="HoverHeader">
    <div id="SiteHeader">
        <div id="MainNav">
           <div id="btnNav"><img src="../../../000Frames/site/images/menu-bt.png" alt="menu"/></div>
           <uc1:mainNav ID="mainNav1" runat="server" />
            <a href="../../../home/a/main" id="logo"></a>
            <div id="InnerLinks">
                <a href="../../../company/a/portfolio" id="portfolioLink">תיק עבודות</a>
                <a href="../../../company/a/customers" id="customersLink">לקוחותינו</a>
                <a href="../../../company/a/about/?ContentID=245" id="aboutLink">אודותנו</a>
                <a href="../../../company/a/contact" id="contactLink">צור קשר</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add couple audio tags on page and play them as described in this article - [Play Sound on :hover | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/).

```
<audio>
    <source src="audio/beep.mp3"></source>
    <source src="audio/beep.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>

<script>
    var audio = $("#mySoundClip")[0];
    $("nav a").mouseenter(function() {
      audio.play();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That needs JavaScript and an audio tag. This is from http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/
For hover sound:

```
<audio id="hover">
    <source src="audio/hover.mp3"></source>
    <source src="audio/hover.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>
var hover = $("#hover")[0];
$(".InnerLinks a").mouseenter(function() {
  hover.play();
});
```

For click sound:

```
<audio id="click">
   <source src="audio/click.mp3"></source>
   <source src="audio/click.ogg"></source>
   Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>

    var click = $("#click")[0];
    $(".InnerLinks a").click(function() {
      click.play();
    });
```

[Demos at CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/)

Comment: i feel a bit robbed, but that's ok :)

Comment: Haha, i had written mine before you posted, i didn't know you had posted until after i did. :)

Comment: well, it's first result on google search, so i'm not surprised :)

Comment: yeah, css tricks is a great resource. i still think there should be a pure css way to do it though.